# Pagination sends too many requests to the server

Tags: angular, angular-material

Pagination sends too many requests to the server. The number of requests becomes equal to the current page. That is, let’s say I am starting to go through the pages 1 page sends one request, 2 page 2 requests, 3 page 3 requests, etc (for example, on  page 15 it sends 15 requests and everything freezes). If  go to the last page and start the transitions from there, the number of requests will begin to increase from 2.

Why is this happening and how to fix it?

service:

```
  fetch(search: string, sort: string, order: string, pageSize: number, page: number): Observable<UsersApi> {
    let params = new HttpParams();
    params = params.append("search", search);
    params = params.append("sort", sort);
    params = params.append("order", order);
    params = params.append("pageSize", pageSize.toString());
    params = params.append("page", page.toString());

    return this.http.get<UsersApi>("/api/users/get_all", { params: params });
  }
```

ts:

```
getUsers() {
  this.sort.sortChange.subscribe(() => (this.paginator.pageIndex = 0));
  merge(this.sort.sortChange, this.paginator.page)
    .pipe(
      startWith({}),
      switchMap(() => {
        this.loading = true;
        return this.usersService!.fetch(this.search, this.sort.active, this.sort.direction, this.pageSize, this.page);
      }),
      map(data => {
        this.loading = false;
        this.isTotalReached = false;
        this.totalItems = data.rowCount;
        return data.users;
      }),
      catchError(() => {
        this.loading = false;
        this.isTotalReached = true;
        return observableOf([]);
      })
    ).subscribe(data => (this.users = data))
}

onPaginateChange(event) {
  this.page = event.pageIndex + 1;
  this.pageSize = event.pageSize;
  this.getUsers();
}
```

html:

```
<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions" [length]="totalItems" [pageSize]="pageSize"
(page)="onPaginateChange($event)" showFirstLastButtons>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of you subscriptions needs to be unsubscribed. Try to make code a little more simpler to see it closes the subscription then. ex:

```
getUsers(){
this.loading = true;
this.usersService.fetch().subscribe(data=>{
        this.loading = false;
        this.isTotalReached = false;
        this.totalItems = data.rowCount;
        this.users = data;
},error=>{
    //handle error
   });
    }
```